# "Rails generate controller" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, secret-key

Does anyone know what this error means? I typed this same command before and it worked perfectly, but then I destroyed the controller and set my secret-key. That was all I did to my app. After that, I get this error everytime I try to create a new controller.

```
    zoltan@zoltan-VPCYB3V1E:~/website$ rails generate controller StaticPages home --no-test-framework
    /home/zoltan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
    from /home/zoltan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zoltan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/zoltan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/bin/rails:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you in project directory + make sure you are using required rvm if installed rvm.

Comment: Yes, to both of those.

Answer (score 1):

What do you see when you type "rvm gemset list"?